# OpenAPI 3 Validation Error : should match format "regex"

Tags: java, regex, jersey, openapi, swagger-editor

I generated an openapi json spec from a Jersey RestApi code I wrote, and one of the constraints I have is a regex negative-lookahead pattern for "LEAGUE-MEMBER" request header. When I convert the json into yaml like so.

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Justice League Delegate Admin Sheet 
  description: 'Log Record for Temp admin access to the WatchTower'
  version: v1
servers:
  - url: https://watchtower.wayne:9443
    description: Generated server url
paths:
  /ent-watchtower-auth/v3/delegate:
    get:
      tags:
        - Search
      summary: Search for a UID
      operationId: searchForUID
      parameters:
        - name: MemberID
          in: header
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          example: JL000000
        - name: LEAGUE-MEMBER
          in: header
          required: true
          schema:
            pattern: '^(?!(?i)\bJOKER\b).*$'
            type: string
          example: BATMAN, JON, HAWKGIRL, ORACLE, FLASH, ANYONEBUTJOKER
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The resulting Delegate History
```

I get the following validation error at swagger.io editor:

```
Structural error at paths./ent-watchtower-auth/v3/delegate.get.parameters.1.schema.pattern
should match format "regex"
format: regex
```

For context on the regex, `'^(?!(?i)\bJOKER\b).*$'` basically allows for any case-insensitive value except 'joker' within the header. (Also, the converted yaml did not wrap the pattern within single quotes, I had to add it later). When I run and test my RESTAPI, the pattern works as expected, and throws ConstraintViolation if the value is "Joker". But I am unable to identify what the editor is trying to call out. Any suggestion and possible fix appreciated, Thank you.

Update: I have pasted MWE for openapi yaml to play around in swagger editor

Comment: Start with the most evident: did you try with double backslashes?

Comment: yes I did, good sire,  like so "\\bJOKER\\b " . I was even suggested triple, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Triple isn't going to help, but quadruple might if this passes through two steps (for example a regexp env var needs to have "\\\\" so that from shell to the program it goes to "\\" which is then "\" in the regexp)

Comment: Are you sure `(?i)` is supported? Try `'^(?!\b[Jj][Oo][Kk][Ee][Rr]\b).*$'`

Comment: Java 8 supports the (?i) in-line case insensitive modifier. `^(?!(?i)\bJOKER\b).*$` https://regex101.com/r/7mP8wI/1 What version are you using ? You might want to make the _Dot Match All_ modifier active as well.

Comment: @sln My Java version is 11, and the pattern works as expected in the code. The only issue is that the swagger.io editor is calling out this pattern as a "structural error" and 
 I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2024-01: The [new v5 Swagger Editor](https://editor-next.swagger.io/) no longer reports validation errors for this.

---

We ran into the same situation.  It seems the spec validator doesn't recognize mode flags like `(?i)` as valid regex.  In our case we worked around it by specifying the mode separately from the expression in the field annotation:

`@Pattern(regexp = "^etc$", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Which was okay for our situation but not ideal, since it doesn't communicate the entire requirement to the spec consumer.